# Connect Snowflake in Python

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I'm trying to connect my Snowflake ODBC to python to create queries. I got results but I see that console display a lot of messages that hide me the results. There any way to just display the results of my query? or another way to connect with Python?

```
import pyodbc

con = pyodbc.connect('DSN=MYODBCNAME;UID=MYUSER')
con.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
con.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
cursor=con.cursor()
cursor.execute("use warehouse WAREHOUSENAME;")
cursor.execute("select * from SCHEMA.DATABASE.TABLE limit 5")

while True:
    row=cursor.fetchone()
    if not row:
        break
    print(row)
```

Here some of those messages, but if I scroll up for some time found the results
[image]

Regards

Comment: Are you using logging module if so share the code

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use the Snowflake Python connector to connect Snowflake to Python:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector.html

Comment: Hi Mike I dont have that kind of permissions I only can access using ODBC conn

Comment: Could you perhaps share more details around what you are trying to do, then?  Why do you have to use ODBC?